# Debezium stream Numeric value decode

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, nestjs, decode, debezium

I have a debezium stream which contains data from a table change.

The numeric values in the stream are stored in a structure ([see more](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/oracle.html) - *Contains a structure with two fields: scale of type INT32 that contains the scale of the transferred value and value of type BYTES containing the original value in an unscaled form.*), and I would need the ID of the changed row, which appears in the stream as the following:

```
{ scale: 0, value: 'BXM=' }
```

How can I decode the "value" field(nodejs) to get the ID, which is an Integer ? - base64 doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(Base64.getDecoder().decode("BXM=")),0);
```